# Applying external force on test charge greater than repulsive force of electric field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electric-fields, acceleration, work

In the textbook, it is written that only that amount of external force is applied that balances the repulsive force of the electric field without producing acceleration. Without acceleration, is it possible for work to be done?

Comment: The test charge might be moving with a constant velocity?

Comment: Do you need any further clarification on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, work is possible without acceleration. Although the net force acting on the charge is zero, the charge can be moving at constant velocity. The external agent is still applying a force against the repulsive force of the electric field through a displacement. This does positive  work, since its force is in the same direction as the displacement. The result is transferring energy to the charge. The change in potential is defined as the work required to move a unit charge between two points.

However, at the same time the electric field is doing an equal amount of negative work on the charge, since its force is in the opposite direction to the displacement of the charge. The net work done on the charge is therefore zero and by the work energy theorem there is no change in kinetic energy of the charge. In doing negative work, the electric field takes the energy supplied by the external agent and stores it as potential energy of the charge/electric field system.

The end result is the external work done on the charge increases the electrical potential energy of the charge/electric field system.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't accept my answer I must assume it didn't help. So I am providing another  answer using work in a gravitational field as an example which is analogous in many ways to work in an electric field.

There is a heavy box on the floor in front of you. You wish to put it on a table a height $h$ above the floor. You lift the box off the surface and then slowly lift it at constant velocity until you reach the top of the table, when you place it on top of the table.

With the exception of the brief period when you first picked the box up and accelerated it, to a final brief period when you slowed it down to put it on the table when it decelerated, you applied a constant force equal to the force of gravity lifting the box at constant velocity.

Let me ask you, do you agree that you did work in lifting that heavy box slowly at constant velocity (zero acceleration) to bring it to rest on the table? If you do, then you would agree that "Without acceleration, it is possible for work to be done".

When you did this work you increased the gravitational potential energy of the box by $mgh$.

The same applies if you did work to move electrical charge against a repulsive constant electric field at constant velocity. In this case, the increase in electrical potential energy of the charge is $QEd$, where $Q$ is the electrical charge in coulombs (analogous to mass $m$), $E$ is the electric field strength in Newtons/coulomb (analogous to "g" in Newtons/kg) and $d$ is the distance the charge is moved in the electric field, analogous to the height the mass $m$ is lifted.

Hope this helps.